# RegEx or Similar - Grab string preceding matched value

Tags: php, regex

Here's the deal, I am handling a OCR text document and grabbing UPC information from it with RegEx. That part I've figured out. Then I query a database and if I don't have record of that UPC I need to go back to the text document and get the description of the product.

The format on the receipt is:

```
NAME OF ITEM 123456789012
OTHER NAME   987654321098
NAME         567890123456
```

So, when I go back the second time to find the name of the item I am at a complete loss. I know how to get to the line where the UPC is, but how can I use something like regex to get the name that precedes the UPC? Or some other method. I was thinking of somehow storing the entire line and then parsing it with PHP, but not sure how to get the line either.

Using PHP.

Comment: Why not keep them together in the first place?  Use a regular expression to retrieve _both_ parts, and store them all in an array using the UPC as the array key and the name as the array value. Then there's no need to go back - you just iterate over your array by `foreach ($products as $UPC => $name)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get all of the names of the items indexed by their UPCs with a regex and [`preg_match_all()`](http://php.net/preg_match_all):

```
$str = 'NAME OF ITEM 123456789012
OTHER NAME   987654321098
NAME         567890123456';
preg_match_all( '/^(.*?)\s+(\d+)/m', $str, $matches);

$items = array();
foreach( $matches[2] as $k => $upc) {
    if( !isset( $items[$upc])) {
        $items[$upc] = array( 'name' => $matches[1][$k], 'count' => 0);
    }
    $items[$upc]['count']++;
}
```

This forms `$items` so it looks like:

```
Array ( 
    [123456789012] => NAME OF ITEM 
    [987654321098] => OTHER NAME 
    [567890123456] => NAME 
)
```

Now, you can lookup any item name you want in `O(1)` time, as seen in [this demo](http://3v4l.org/AvvN9):

```
echo $items['987654321098']; // OTHER NAME
```

Comment: My UPC match is a bit more complex. `(?:^|\D)(\d{12})(?=\D|$)` I need to make sure I get EXACTLY 12 digit numbers that aren't a part of other numbers. So if I replace mine with your `(\d+)` will that work. Do I need to make it `(?:^|\D)(\d{12})(?=\D|$)+)`?

Comment: Well you're matching `^` or `$` in your regex, which won't work. To incorporate that, you can try something like this: `/^(.*?)\s+(\d{12})(?=\D|$)/m'`

Comment: Any way to handle duplicate items? Same item twice? I think I use the + or g but anywhere I put it it dies

Comment: Sure, what's the desired functionality? To overwrite, or keep a list of all the item names for a particular UPC?

Comment: If the same item exists twice, have it twice in the array. Each UPC will have a unique name, but each name/UPC combo could exist more than once. I want to know the receipt had multiple items even if they are the same.

Comment: Nah, you can't do that, because the array is indexed by UPC, because the UPC is supposed to be unique. If it exists twice, why would you want it twice in the array? You could keep an array of names in the array, though: `Array ( 
    [123456789012] => Array( NAME OF ITEM, SAME ITEM DIFFERENT NAME)
)` OR, you can keep a `count` of all the times you see a UPC in the array.

Comment: Damn. Well I am logging purchases. So if someone purchased 2 of the same item, I want to know that. I can't keep a count though from the current thing because matches will only contain the uniques

Comment: Oh, in that case that's easy, you can track the number of times you see the UPC. I'll update my answer.

Comment: I'm now trying to do this in coldfusion. I don't understand what your `m` means at the end. It's outside the regex isn't it/ What does that do? I can't find documentation

Comment: It's the [multiline modifier](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php).

Answer (score 0):

You can find the string preceding a value you know with the following regex:

```
$receipt = "NAME OF ITEM 123456789012\n" .
           "OTHER NAME   987654321098\n" .
           "NAME         567890123456";
$upc = '987654321098';
if (preg_match("/^(.*?) *{$upc}/m", $receipt, $matches)) {
    $name = $matches[1];
    var_dump($name);
}
```

The /m flag on the regex makes the ^ work properly with multi-line input.
The `?` in `(.*?)` makes that part non-greedy, so it doesn't grab all the spaces

Answer (score 0):

It would be simpler if you grabbed both the name and the number at the same time during the initial pass. Then, when you check the database to see if the number is present, you already have the name if you need to use it. Consider:

```
preg_match_all('^([A-Za-z ]+) (\d+)$', $document, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);

foreach ($matches as $match) {
    $name = $match[1];
    $number = $match[2];

    if (!order_number_in_database($number)) {
        save_new_order($number, $name);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use lookahead assertions to match string preceding the UPC.
http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.assertions.php

By something like this: `^\S*(?=\s*123456789012)` substituting the UPC with the UPC of the item you want to find.

Answer (score 0):

I'm lazy, so I would just use one regex that gets both parts in one shot using matching groups. Then, I would call it every time and put each capture group into name and upc variables. For cases in which you need the name, just reference it.

Use this type of regex:

```
/([a-zA-Z ]+)\s*(\d*)/
```

Then you will have the name in the $1 matching group and the UPC the $2 matching group. Sorry, it's been a while since I've used php, so I can't give you an exact code snippet.

Note: the suggested regex assumes you'll only have letters or spaces in your "names" if that's not the case, you'll have to expand the character class.